# How can I get dynamically changeable "id" from JSON? (Done)

Tags: java

I need to take **id** from this JSON how can I get it? **id** dynamically changeable.

```
[{"id":"e28bad5b-661e-4026-983f-60e809a9cd32","name":"kjgkjgk","status":"HEALTHY","containers":[{"id":"f397c436-7701-4965-acff-980bee1b1ebd","environmentId":"e28bad5b-661e-4026-983f-60e809a9cd32","hostname":"master1d1ea96172224bff98214e57f1839a48"]}
```

Comment: could you provide a little bit more code? thats to less.

Comment: @Nikolai sure..
P.S.: First of all, take a look at what is [JSON](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/) and after you will also notice a problem in your format

Comment: after going through the @drgPP comment , u can use a JSON library. e.g. http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys it was easer then it was seem. Open FireBug, Open IntellijIdea, take xpath, name it like **data**

```
String id = data.getText().substring(8, 44);
```

That's it.

Comment: That works exactly only for the example data. Any other json object where only the slightest change happens, say the "id" property name becomes unquoted or a space is added after the semicolon, the code fails because the value is no longer at position 8.

Comment: it doesn't fail, it works perfect, data change between 8 and 44 includes. I don't know, maybe you are right, but in my case numbers and letters are changeable

Comment: You don't have to try to understand what I'm saying, its only a matter of time before you see it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

for this first you need to create the object of json and pass the jsonobject name in this object.
by using this object you can fetch the string tag easily.

```
String data=[{"id":"e28bad5b-661e-4026-983f-60e809a9cd32","name":"kjgkjgk","status":"HEALTHY","containers":[{"id":"f397c436-7701-4965-acff-980bee1b1ebd","environmentId":"e28bad5b-661e-4026-983f-60e809a9cd32","hostname":"master1d1ea96172224bff98214e57f1839a48"]};

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
}
```

as above for id do the rest

Comment: You cannot do it diretly. It's an array.

Comment: @hemant1087, thanks for you answer. +1 to your karma) For me is interesting to, how to do it through array.